# How to configure cgminer to mine with the CPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, bitcoin

I installed the cgminer to try to get into a bitcoin mining pool, but I have no GPU. I know that mining with the CPU is not very eficient, but I want to know how to configure cgminer to mine with the CPU? Because I just want to test it.
I installed the cgminer by the ubuntu software center.

Comment: See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/how-to-configure-cgminer-with-cpu

Comment: Get cpuminer, or don't bother. I figured out it would take me 168 years to make $1. It's orders of magnitude too slow. It used to be marginally practical but the difficulty factor keeps increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, the latest version have'nt support for cpuming, until version 2.11.4 adding --enable-cpumining  when you call ./configure
 Better use bfgminer

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:unit3/bfgminer

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get install bfgminer
```

and configure,

[More Info at my blog (spanish)](http://cur.lv/5c6yr)